# Is the American economy on the same path when it had a massive crash in 2007? Is there another bubble coming

Tags: macroeconomics, debt, usa

I guess I should not be asking for technical answers, because I've learned economists are not to predict things like this.  Yet from current data, and this article that reviewed said data: http://www.ronpaullibertyreport.com/archives/this-new-bubble-is-even-bigger-than-the-subprime-fiasco

It seems we are on the verge of a second bubble burst and financial crisis.  President Trump and his cabinet have only done bad things for the lower classes of America.  Defunding public education, making a mess of healthcare, taking is out of the TTP which gives China power in the global economy, and now with the STUDENT LOAN DEBT BUBBLE...it seems in a few years or less, we are going to hit the crash again.  Our economy has not recovered from the last.  I saw the film,"The Big Short" and the world nearly ended in an economic sense in 2007.  If we hit it again, things aren't looking good.  What do you think, from current trends and data?